# What is a well-defined homomorphism from $Aut(G)$ to $Aut(G^{ab})$?

Tags: group-theory

> Construct a well-defined homomorphism from $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(G^{ab})$.

Note that $G^{ab}$ is the abelianization of $G$, and is equivalent to the quotient $G/[G,G]$, where $[G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$. I know that every automorphism on $G$ takes an element of the commutator subgroup to another element in the commutator subgroup but I'm not sure how to use that, exactly.

What's an intuitive, well-defined homomorphism from $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(G^{ab})$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\pi:G\to G^{ab}$ be the canonical projection map, and let $\phi$ be an automorphism of $G$. By the universal property of the quotient, there is a unique homomorphism $\bar{\phi}:G^{ab}\to G^{ab}$ such that $\bar{\phi}\circ \pi=\pi\circ \phi$.

$\bar{\phi}$ is surjective because $\phi$ and $\pi$ are, and if $\bar{\phi}(\bar{g})=0$ then $\pi(\phi(g))=0$, so $\phi(g)\in [G,G]$, meaning that $\bar{g}=0$ since automorphisms map $[G,G]$ into itself. Therefore $\bar{\phi}$ is an automorphism of $G^{ab}$.